# PDO error duplicate data on SteamAuth

Tags: php

I am currently using steam auth which I then translated to integrate my code into MySQL.
Unfortunately, I get a message that informs me that the table already exists.
I would like to have a code that allows me to update the data if needed, but unfortunately, I can not find on google.
Here is my code in PDO.

```
<?php

function newPDO() {
    $host = 'x';
    $db   = 'x';
    $user = 'x';
    $pass = 'x';


    $dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db";
    $opt = [
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
    ];
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);
    return $pdo;
}

{
    $pdo = newPDO();
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO players (uid, name, avatar) VALUES (:uid, :name, :avatar)');
    $stmt->execute(['uid' => $_SESSION['steam_steamid'], 'name' => $_SESSION['steam_personaname'], 'avatar' => $_SESSION['steam_avatar']]);
    if($pdo->lastInsertId()) {
        //login successfull
        return true;
    } else {
        //registration failed
        return false;
    }
}

if(!isset($_SESSION['steamid'])) {
    loginbutton("rectangle"); //login button

}  else {
    include ('steamauth/userInfo.php');
    //Protected content
    echo $steamprofile['personaname'];
    echo '<img src="'.$steamprofile['avatar'].'" title="" alt="" />'; // Display their avatar!

    logoutbutton("rectangle");
}    
?>
```

And finaly this is the error code my php tells me

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '76561197992043760' for key 'uid'' in C:\xampp\htdocs\inc\login.php:23 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\inc\login.php(23): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php(52): include('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\inc\login.php on line 23

Can you help me solve the prob ?

Comment: there is already a row in your table that has a `uid` of `76561197992043760`

Comment: i know , i want say if is possible the pdo overwrite ?

Comment: Overwrite = UPDATE and not INSERT Are you saying you want to amend an existing row?

Comment: if i want use UPDATE what my code will looks like ?

Comment: [Mysql Manual -  UPDATE Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html)

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(uid, name, avatar) VALUES (?, ?, ?)' at line 1' in C:\xampp\htdocs\inc\login.php:35 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\inc\login.php(35): 
This is when i use UPDATE
PDO->prepare('UPDATE players ...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php(52): include('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...') #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\inc\login.php on line 35

Answer (score -1):

You can verify first if filed exist with SELECT

If not exist create the row with INSERT

Else update the record with UPDATE